# java.lang.IllegalStateException: calling verify is not allowed in record state in easymock

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I have a very big Integration test where it is failing with **calling verify is not allowed in record state** in easy mock.

I could not figure out what exactly causing the issue.

in @After there are some mocks below

```
@After
public void after(){
  mock(a,b,c);
  replay();
   verify(a,b,c);
}
```

exception is coming at verify, if someone has a clue what could be possible scenarios.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the mocks to `replay`. And I don't get your mocking part. Please, next time, give a real example.

```
@After
public void after(){
  var a = mock(A.class);
  var b = mock(B.class);
  var c = mock(C.class);
  //  ... expectations ...
  replay(a, b, c);
  // ... test...
  verify(a, b, c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons that you can get the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: calling verify is not allowed in record state`.

If there are no calls to `expect(...).andReturn(...)` calls, or `expectLastCall()` then there will be nothing for it to verify, and you will get this error.

Another easily overlooked error is when you use `PowerMock`, `EasyMock` and `EasyMock`'s `strictControl` which all have their versions of the various `expect` calls. If you accidentally use one to create the mocked classes, and other to verify the calls, it will cause the same issue as above, since the specific package doesn't see any matching `expect` calls.

Additionally I'd recommend using `replayAll();` and `verifyAll();` to avoid using explicitly stating each of the expected calls.